# start a process (trigger a .net core DLL) from within electron app

Tags: c#, .net-core, electron

In my solution, I have an electron application and a console application (.Net core DLL), from withing the electron app, I would like to trigger that DLL and pass it some parameters and wait for its response. Below is my code snippet, however, it doesn't trigger the DLL.

```
 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet"); 
 start.Arguments = $"MyLibrary.dll"
 start.CreateNoWindow = false;
 start.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
 start.RedirectStandardError = false; 
 var process = Process.Start(start);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `Process.Start` throw an exception?

Comment: No, it doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: What happens if you add `process.WaitForExit();` after the Start line? Does it fall right through? Try doing an absolute path to the DLL `start.Arguments = "\"c:\\files\\thepath\\MyLibrary.dll\"";`